# Shadowing vs overriding?

Tags: c#-4.0

This is one of the examples in the msdn related to shadowing and overriding:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class A
    {
        public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
        public virtual void G() { Console.WriteLine("A.G"); }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        new public void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
        public override void G() { Console.WriteLine("B.G"); }
    }
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            B b = new B();
            A a = b;
            a.F();
            b.F();
            a.G();
            b.G();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}


A.F();
B.F();
B.G();
B.G();

I was expecting the out put will be 
B.F(); //change is here
B.F();
B.G();
B.G();
```

since A a = b;
a holds the b object reference and hence it has a call derived class function.

Why is the function of A called?

Answer (score 0):

At run-time, while a is indeed a variable of the type B, it's explicitly a variable of type A (A a = b;), and so at run-time since a is declared as being a type A, the F() method of A is called.

Hope this helped!

N.S.

Comment: A a =b; it means that variable a has only the data of class A not of b

Comment: Yeah, but while b points to an object of type B, the pointer of a is of type A, so at compile-time methods being called on a will be implicitly the implementation of A. It will hold the data of class A, but it will still, however, be of type B (which is also of type A).